# Bash : getting webpage content into variable with curl / wget

Tags: bash, curl, wget

When I execute these lines :

```
res1=$(curl -sSL http://ipecho.net/plain | xargs echo)
echo $res1
```

I get this output, meaning I'm actually able to put the contents of [this webpage](http://ipecho.net/plain) into a variable :

```
92.12.242.124
```

========================

Now, when I try the same with [another URL](https://raw.github.com/n-marshall/system-setup/master/common/configs/.gitignore_global) :

```
res2=$(curl -sSL https://raw.github.com/n-marshall/system-setup/master/common/configs/.gitignore_global | xargs echo)
echo $res2
```

I get this output :

```
xargs: unterminated quote
```

Could anyone guide me into getting the content of the second link into a variable ? Thank you.

(My actual goal is to then copy it / append it to a local file, if that changes anything to the answer)

==================================

EDIT : I haven't been able to achieve the same with wget either, but any solution with wget is welcome too

EDIT2 : to provide some more context...

I'm looking for a solution that could :

- work on system files (i.e. with sudo, but the redirect doesn't play nice with sudo)
- pass this as a parameter to another function

like this one (which appends but adds a separator) :

```
append() {
    if [ "$1" = "--separate" ]; then
        [[ -s $3 ]] && printf "\n#----------------------------------------------------------------\n\n" | sudo tee -a $3
        echo $2 | sudo tee -a $3
        printf "\n" | sudo tee -a $3
    else
        echo $1 | sudo tee -a $2
    fi
}
```

Comment: `res2=$(curl -sSL https://raw.github.com/n-marshall/system-setup/master/common/configs/.gitignore_global); echo "$res2"`

Comment: Try `| xargs -0 echo`

Comment: Why are you even using xargs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a variable if you just want to copy `curl` output to a local file. Just redirect the `curl` command to your file:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.github.com/n-marshall/system-setup/master/common/configs/.gitignore_global > file
```

To append the output to an existing file:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.github.com/n-marshall/system-setup/master/common/configs/.gitignore_global >> file
```

**Edit**:

With `sudo`:

```
sudo bash -c 'curl -sSL https://raw.github.com/n-marshall/system-setup/master/common/configs/.gitignore_global > file2'
```

Comment: Works on files that require no sudo... do you have a solution for files that require sudo ? by the way I don't understand the downvote either... let me upvote that to compensate

Comment: Do you have an error? It works for me. Try to change the last command for `sudo bash -c "curl -sSL $url > $file"`.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks ! I didn't think I could simply pass variables to subshells like this